# ACF as background-image with hover

Tags: wordpress, background, hover, advanced-custom-fields

On a page, I want to display a list with all of the associated childpages. On the child pages, I have added 2 custom fields for images. "normal" for normal state, "hover" for hover state.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type'      => 'page',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
'order'          => 'ASC',
'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
);                                                              
$parent = new WP_Query( $args );                                    
if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>                                   
    <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?> 
        <?php 
            $image = get_field('normal');
            $hover = get_field('hover');
            if( !empty($image) ): ?>                                                
                <style type="text/css"> 
                     .preview-page { 
                         background-image: url('<?php echo $image['url']; ?>'); 
                     } 
                     .preview-page:hover { 
                         background-image: url('<?php echo $hover['url']; ?>'); 
                     }    
                </style>                                            
        <?php endif; ?>
        <a class="preview-page" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">                                            
            <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
        </a><!-- end #category-name -->                         

    <?php endwhile; ?>                                  
<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

My problem is, that all child pages are shown with their own title, but all with the same background image (the one of the last child). How can I achieve that every child page has the right background image? I guess it's some failure within the loop.

When I display the image in a regular img-tag, they're shown right.

**UPDATE:** here's a testlink where you can see the principle, but always the 2 images of the last child page: http://dev.communicaziun.ch/wuest/jetzt-bei-wuest/

Comment: Is the image you are getting the post parent image? 'post_parent'    => $post->ID,

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. On the parent page I'm trying to get the images of the child pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because each  tag inside your loop is overriding the styles in the previous  tag. Try something like this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
'post_type'      => 'page',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
'order'          => 'ASC',
'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
);                                                              
$parent = new WP_Query( $args );                                    
if ( $parent->have_posts() ) :
    $i=0; ?>                                   
    <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?> 
        <?php 
            $i++;
            $image = get_field('normal');
            $hover = get_field('hover');
            if( !empty($image) ): ?>                                                
                <style type="text/css"> 
                     .preview-page<?php echo $i; ?> { 
                         background-image: url('<?php echo $image['url']; ?>'); 
                     } 
                     .preview-page<?php echo $i; ?>:hover { 
                         background-image: url('<?php echo $hover['url']; ?>'); 
                     }    
                </style>                                            
        <?php endif; ?>
        <a class="preview-page preview-page<?php echo $i; ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">                                            
            <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
        </a><!-- end #category-name -->                         

    <?php endwhile; ?>                                  
<?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

This will set each of your  items with the class preview-page to have a unique identifier. That unique identifier will appear in your  tags as well, so that styles do not get overwritten.

So your first  will appear like this:

```
<a class="preview-page preview-page1" href="MY LINK HERE">                                            
    <span>MY TITLE HERE</span>
</a>
```

And the second  will appear like this:

```
<a class="preview-page preview-page2" href="MY LINK HERE">                                            
    <span>MY TITLE HERE</span>
</a>
```

and so on...

Then your  for the first element will be:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    .preview-page1 { 
        background-image: url('MY IMAGE URL'); 
    } 
    .preview-page1:hover { 
        background-image: url('MY OTHER IMAGE URL'); 
    }    
</style>
```

and your second  will be the same, but with a "2" at the end of the class names instead of the 1.